# selectize drop item to get in front always

Tags: jquery, html, css, selectize.js

hello all i am using selectize plugin to create tags to my site everything is good except that the drop down item gets overlapped by my other divs.

i want them to behave like select items which are absolute and always in frnt.

i have tried positioning with absolute and z-index but no help
if you could suggest me something about the plugin it would be great.

```
     <script src="tags/selectize.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="tags/selectize.default.css"/>
 <div class="control-group">
                <select id="<?=$getid_i?>" multiple name="dept[]" class="demo-default" >
                    <option value=""><?=$placehol?></option>
                    <?php if ($tagwhats =='depts'){
                 // something to get ....
                } else if($tagwhats =='skills'){
                 // something here ...
                } ?>
                </select>
            </div>
 <script>
                var eventHandler = function(name) {
                return function() {
                    console.log(name, arguments);
                    $('#log').append('<div><span class="name">' + name + '</span></div>');
                };
            };
            var $select = $('#'+"<?=$getid_i?>").selectize({
                create          : true,
                onChange        : eventHandler('onChange'),
                onItemAdd       : eventHandler('onItemAdd'),
                onItemRemove    : eventHandler('onItemRemove'),
                onOptionAdd     : eventHandler('onOptionAdd'),
                onOptionRemove  : eventHandler('onOptionRemove'),
                onDropdownOpen  : eventHandler('onDropdownOpen'),
                onDropdownClose : eventHandler('onDropdownClose'),
                onFocus         : eventHandler('onFocus'),
                onBlur          : eventHandler('onBlur'),
                onInitialize    : eventHandler('onInitialize'),
                });
                </script>
```

Comment: what i am doing is just calling this inside a pre created div with 300px width and 40px height i want when the drop down shows it should get over the div and show. right now it shows but it gets hidden as the height of main div is 40px only

Answer (score 5):

None of the above answers worked for me.  I just had to set the `dropdownParent` property in my configuration.

```
dropdownParent: 'body'
```

https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md

Note - I am using Angular 7.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer and works perfect.

Answer (score 2):

In selectize.css you can change the `z-index` for the dropdown. The following works on my site:

```
.selectize-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10000; /* adjust as necessary */
  border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
  background: #ffffff;
  margin: -1px 0 0 0;
  border-top: 0 none;  
}
```

Comment: Sorry but not working for me what i am doing is just calling this inside a pre created div with 300px width and 40px height i want when the drop down shows it should get over the div and show. right now it shows but it gets hidden as the height of main div is 40px only

Comment: This is useless because the z-index property is ignored when the position property has a value of 'absolute'.

Answer (score 2):

Forget about the selectize.css classes. What works for me is:
Create another class with the following:

```
.myNewClass {
   position: absolute !important;
   z-index: 999;
}
```

And put this class inside your `<select>` tag.
After this you should realign your element, but the problem might be solved.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap framework and it's working fine

```css
.selectize-dropdown {
    z-index: 9999!important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use bootstrap 3 or bootstrap 2 don't forget to load the css as well. You can find the css files [here](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/tree/master/dist/css). Please load your css accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I am using UIKit 3.x and this works for me

```
.selectize-dropdown-content {
    z-index: 999;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid #e5e5e5; // this is optional
}
```